# Why isn't this d3 hexagon drawing correctly?

Tags: javascript, path, d3.js, area

I have made a code to make a simple hexagon but for some reason it is not drawing correctly. I am using "A", xDiff and yDiff as variables so I can change the size and location of the hexagon on the fly but it has a weird "tail". Is one of my points wrong? Oh, and _s32 is the square root of 3 divided by two.

```
        var _s32 = (Math.sqrt(3)/2);
        var A = 25;
        var xDiff = 100;
        var yDiff = 1000;
        var pointData = [[A+xDiff, 0+yDiff], [A/2+xDiff, A*_s32+yDiff], [-A/2+xDiff, A*_s32+yDiff], [-A+xDiff, 0+yDiff],
        [-A/2+xDiff, -A*_s32+yDiff], [A/2+xDiff, -A*_s32+yDiff]];
        var svgContainer = d3.select("body") //create container
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", 1000)
                .attr("height", 1000);

        var enterElements = svgContainer.selectAll("path.area") //draw elements
                .data([pointData]).enter().append("path")
                .style("fill", "#ff0000")
                .attr("d", d3.svg.area());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, `yDiff` being at 1000 positions your hexagon nearly outside of your SVG, so you should change it to, like, 100.

Next, you're using `d3.svg.area()`, which is built to do more than just draw a path corresponding to the points you pass into it; rather, it's actually trying to add points in order to draw what would normally be the area under the graph, which in your case is meaningless. Instead, just use the `d3.svg.line()` function, which will just do what you need without trying to add any other points.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LJuRp/